# Use of unresolved identifier 'Shared' at Haneke framework

Tags: swift, frameworks, haneke

I imported the Haneke framework at my Swift project. When I trying to run app at iPad, it builds, and all is working wonderfull, but when I trying to run app at simulator, I get an error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIGAe.png)
I can't use functions from framework.. Why?

Comment: Why not post the actual code in your question ?